# What is this component in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, expandablelistview

I tried to reproduce this component in my app :

[image]

Is it an `expandableListView` ?

Because I tried to use `expandablelistview` and I get this result :

[image]

Comment: It's just `spinner` with `dropdownView`. go to [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

Comment: I have no idea why @wawanopoulos was downvoted for asking this question. In my opinion, it is a legitimate question a newbie could have when trying to emulate certain behavior in their own app.

Comment: This question shouldnt be downvoted. It has the right quality, because its straight to the point, with an example and the answer isnt as obvious as some might think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called spinner and Spinners provide a quick way to select one value from a set. In the default state, a spinner shows its currently selected value.

refer this link `http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html`